# only 'click' event works, how to add 'keyup' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a `iframe` in that, I do have 2 divs. one is editable(typeable) another one is not.

when something typed in `editable` element, i require to send the text to server. I am trying to hear from the event, but i not able to get anything.

but only the `click` event works!

i tried with promise approach too.. no luck. always i am getting the `iframe` body as target instead of getting the children(`div`)  how to overcome with this issue?

here is my function:

```
$.when(iframebody.append(div).append(msgDiv)).done(function(output){
        output.find('.mceEditable').on('click', function(e){
            console.log("hi", $(e.target)); //works!
        });
});

$.when(iframebody.append(div).append(msgDiv)).done(function(output){
    output.find('.mceEditable').on('keyup', function(e){
        console.log("hi", $(e.target)); // show the parent (body)
    });
});
```

html:

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body " data-id="tinyeditor1" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
    <p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
    <div class="txtMsg mceNonEditable" data-mce-contenteditable="false" style="margin-bottom: 5px; background: rgb(242, 242, 242);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar tempor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, n</div>
    <div class="msgText mceEditable" data-mce-contenteditable="true" style="margin-bottom: 5px; outline: 0px;">
    <span class="nameInfo" style="display:none">XYZ - Says : </span>&nbsp; some</div>
</body>
```

**Update**

i am trying to switch on and off the body editable property, but no luck

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7z7y382r/1/)

Comment: You realize that your body is also `contenteditable`?

Comment: Adding to what Mouser said - it's the body itself that receives the `keyup` event, because the body is what's `contenteditable`.

Comment: yes, the body is editable, but how can i over come with this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use mouseup instead of keyup?

**HTML**

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body " data-id="tinyeditor1" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
    <p>
        <br data-mce-bogus="1"></br>
    </p>
    <div class="txtMsg mceNonEditable" data-mce-contenteditable="false" style="margin-bottom: 5px; background: rgb(242, 242, 242);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar tempor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, n</div>
    <div class="msgText mceEditable" data-mce-contenteditable="true" style="margin-bottom: 5px; outline: 0px;"> <span class="nameInfo" style="display:none">XYZ - Says : </span>
&nbsp; some</div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
$('.mceEditable').click(function (e) {
    console.log("hi", $(e.target))
});
$('.mceEditable').mouseup(function (e) {
    console.log("hi", $(e.target));
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7z7y382r/)

Comment: yes, click is working but `mouseup` not. how to get the mouse up from the child? even your fiddle

Comment: I am using chrome but  i require to make it work with `chrome` and `ie9`

Comment: Make sure you're clicking on the word 'some'. That's the only part that triggers either event. Beyond that, I'm not sure why it isn't working for you -- I'm using Chrome too, and I'm not having any problems.

Comment: exactly this is working on `click` but i am not getting `mouseup`.

Comment: Can you try a different browser?

Comment: I tried with `chrome`, `ie9` and `firefox` - i am running with `windows7` - what about you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72519/discussion-between-samuelms-and-3gwebtrain).